# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Tags: sql, boolean-expression

```
select * from srs_sce
left join sits..srs_cbo as cbostart 
       on cbostart.cboayrc = scj_ayrc and 
          cbostart.cbo_crsc = scj_crsc and 
          cbostart.cbo_blok = scj_blok and 
          cbostart.cbo_occl = scj_occl 
left join ins_ayr on ayr_code = scj_ayrc
where isnull(scj_hesd,
             isnull(cbostart.cbo_begd,
                    **convert(varchar,year(ayr_begd))+'-10-01'))**
```

My code is above I have a problem with the convert I am trying to convert an int and then a varchar. Can anyone help please?

Comment: What are you trying to convert to int and what are you trying covert into varchar? be specific

Comment: What condition are you trying to test in the `where` clause? At the moment, you are just giving it a condition that should evaluate as something like `where '2011-10-01'`, which doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `where` clause - you are giving it an expression that will evaluate to a string expression, but the `where` clause is used to specify conditions that must be satisfied to return records.

You need to rewrite the `where` clause to specify records to be selected.